# Using IAM to control access of AWS Cognito user when invoking lambda via API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

My web app authenticates a user against AWS Cognito to obtain temporary credentials. Based on the standard trust relationship access to API gateway (`"Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"`) and s3 (`"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"]`) is granted.

In s3 I have multiple objects for which I need to control the access based on the users purchases. So one user may only be able to access object A and C, another one only B and C.

There is also an API endpoint returning the content of the bucket, which also needs to be aware of the users permissions in that it should hide objects that the users isn't allowed to see and it should flag objects that are read-only.

I have been playing around with accessing the cognito identity id in lambda, but since objects can't be uploaded through lambda, I need to allow some direct access to s3. So really I need a solution based on IAM - I believe...

So my big questions is, how do I get from the one IAM role with a trust relationship for cognito to controlling access for every user in congito?

**Update**

The users purchases are actually not yet stored somewhere, as I still need to figure out the best place for them. Since I already have dynamo DB, it seems like a good fit.

Comment: With this type of granularity, you need to define exactly how the business logic needs to express the permissions.  This seems too complex for built-in capabilities.  What about this... create a Lambda function that evaluates the user's "purchases" (worth mentioning: these are stored *where*?) and for requests to read S3, if the user is authorized to make the request, generate a pre-signed URL inside the Lambda function and return an HTTP 302 redirect to send the browser to the S3 endpoint.  Cognito creds would not need to be used against S3, then. Seems much simpler.  Thoughts?

Comment: The lambda function for pre-signed URLs is a really good idea! In fact, I'm already using this. Only that currently the lambda function does not know who the calling user is. I've tried to get this information in lambda, but it didn't seem reliable (context.identity.cognito_identity_id is null). If there is a right way of doing it in lambda it would be a very good solution. I will add an update on where the purchases are stored) .

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've checked the link and followed the instructions but ran into a failure when accessing the api through the android sdk. It seems that others face the same problem. Basically I can't seem to get credentials from the user pool, but only from the identity pool. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a working example online. AWS docs are rather light on that as well...